# Declare and use Array - Getting Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a For Loop to clear contents of cells if the previous column is empty.  I build an array because I have to separate columns to check.  Here is my code:

```
    With calcCalculations

Dim rng As Range
Dim xRange(1 To 2) As String

xRange(1) = "CA"
xRange(2) = "CD"

    **For Each rng In .Columns(xRange).SpecialCells(xlBlanks)**
        rng.Offset(, 1).ClearContents

                Next

    End With
```

However, when I run my code I get a Type MisMatch error in the highlighted line
Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: A Type Mismatch Error means you attempted to convert a value to another type in a way that is not valid. I forget, does VBA have "call stacks" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *index* the array:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim xRange(1 To 2) As String

xRange(1) = "CA"
xRange(2) = "CD"
For i = 1 To 2
    For Each rng In .Columns(xRange(i)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
        rng.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
    Next
Next i
```